# Skype "notify me only" on some emoticon

Tags: skype, notifications

In Skype Conversation Settings, there is an option to "Notify me only if these words are mentioned" ("Enter single words separated by spaces").

However, this does not work for me if I enter `(*)`, the skype character sequence for the Star emoticon.

How do I put notification alert on an emoticon in Skype?

Staff members notify us about important events on a skype chat where there is a flood of irrelevant information also going, so it would matter. (Unfortunately we couldn't yet agree on a more viable announcement alternative.)